# Why doesn't matching on a List[Any] generate an unchecked type warning?

Tags: scala, type-erasure, scala-2.12

Anyone know why these generate unchecked-type warnings...

```
def anyMap(a: Any): Unit = a match {
  case _: Map[Any, Any] => 
}
//warning: non-variable type argument Any in type pattern scala.collection.immutable.Map[Any,Any] (the underlying of Map[Any,Any]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure

def intList(a: Any): Unit = a match {
  case _: List[Int] =>
}
//warning: non-variable type argument Int in type pattern List[Int] (the underlying of List[Int]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

...but this does not?

```
def anyList(a: Any): Unit = a match {
  case _: List[Any] =>
}
//[crickets]
```

Mostly just curious. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala can verify that the type of something satisfies `List[Any]` simply by checking that it is a `List`. This is because [the list type](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) is covariant in its first argument, so even if you pass it a `List[Int]` or a `List[Double]`, those are still subclasses are `List[Any]`, so all the compiler has to do is check `List`, which it can do at runtime. The type erasure doesn't affect its ability to do this.

Checking if something is a `List[Int]` would require knowing the actual type of the elements, which *is* erased at runtime, and Scala can't do the same trick with `Map[Any, Any]` since [the map type](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/collection/Map.html) is invariant in its first argument. So while `Map[Any, Int]` is a subclass of `Map[Any, Any]`, `Map[Int, Any]` is not. Thus, Scala would have to be able to check the type of the first argument, which it cannot do at runtime.

More about variance can be found [in the docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html).